# The opacity works with the hover but not the background color. Why?

Tags: css

I want to create a black transparent overlay on 4 images, keeping the size and if possible add some text with the hover. I've looked preview answers but it doesn't work for me. Begginer. Could you help me ?

HTML

```
<section class="image">

    <img src="images/JOHN.jpg" alt="john" id="John" >
    <img src="images/CITIES.jpg" alt="cities" id="Cities">
    <img src="images/HOMIES.jpg" alt="homies" id="Homies"> 
    <img src="images/HASARD1.jpg" alt="hasard" "Hasard"> 

</section>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 47%;
  height: auto;
}

#John:hover {
  background: black;
  ;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* i also tried */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7))
  /* the only thing that works on it is the opacity */
}

section.image {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The background you are trying to apply will not appear on the `<img>` tags because your image is blocking it out.

Think of your `<img>` tag as a layered element, the top is your actual picture, and below it is the container where the background is set.  Since your image fills up the entire container, your background will never appear.

What you want to do instead is create an element that appears on-top of your image, and appears upon hover.

In order to do this, you need to first wrap your `<img>` tags with an element, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="img-link">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</a>
```

I used an `<a>` tag because I'm assuming you want something clickable.

Next we can apply some basic styling that inserts an element after the `<a>` tag, and makes it appears upon hover.  The result is something like this:

```css
.img-link {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.img-link:after {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.img-link:hover:after {
  opacity: 1; /* show overlay */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="img-link">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</a>
```

Comment: Sweet explanation, nice transition just for the eye too, haha! ;)

Comment: Have to take care of those eyes, ya know ;)

Comment: Small point: Possibly bear in mind that the `img` tag is an inline element, without the image it wouldn't actually have any area to place a background. You need to place backgrounds onto block elements, like `div`s.

Comment: Absolutely with you, would have had to downvote instead of upvoting if you didn't ;)

Comment: @ChuckLeButt - hence is why I set the `<a>` to an `inline-block` which will accept and render the background appropriately ;)

Comment: @Axel I know *you* understand this, I was thinking of Tarekis. You might want to include an explanation about that stuff in your answer.

Comment: :) masters, still not working for me... Is it the width: 47%  height:auto and section.image: text-aligned that is causing the problem ?

Comment: If you want a width constraint for your images, put it on `.img-link` instead.  **Example:** `.img-link { width: 47%; }`

Comment: doesn't work neither. It only takes the constraint when i place it on the img tag. don't get it...

Comment: @Axel Oops, I meant **ines b.** not Tarekis.

Comment: sorry, also add `.img-link img { width: 100%; }` to force the images to match the width of the `.img-link` parent container.

Comment: Check your code, it should work.  See this fiddle and compare to what you're doing: https://jsfiddle.net/c04cfcdj/

Comment: @Axel :) Now it works !!! Something was missing in the code like left:0 in .img-link:after. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google of "CSS image caption hover" reveals a lot of links which you'll find useful :) Take this for example: http://demo.hongkiat.com/css3-image-captions/index.html

Basically you cannot just do it with an img. You need some additional HTML around it to create the black background. For example, here's a very basic jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/outfg5ym/

Notice how I've wrapped my img inside a div:

```
<div class="black">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg">
</div>
```

The div creates a black background behind the image, and then when hovering over the div, the opacity of the image is dropped back.

Comment: Nice effort, simple and working, although not as detailed as @Axel 's answer, +10.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a filter to image to achieve similar effect.
Something like this:

```
img:hover {
 -webkit-filter:brightness(70%);
 filter:brightness(70%);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d6tce9g8/1/

Also, there are a lot of filters available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Browser support of filter: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: thanks..i don't know if i can put some text over the img with this method but at least it works keeping the size of my images.